# Open Statistica *.sta file under Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistica

I have *.sta file with dataset. How to open this Statistica *.sta file under Python3? Is there any package for that?

Comment: AFAIK it's tough. Can you get Statisitica and convert it to more handy format?

Comment: In general, you would need Statistica and use the COM object model to retrieve the data or save it to a format you desire like .csv or .xls. Statistica Workspaces have a Python code node such that you can write Python code and use it within Statistica.